# What does "pleasant to a fault" mean?

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

Googling didn't help.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: [to a fault](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/%E2%80%94%E2%80%94-to-a-fault?q=to+a+fault)

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139572/meaning-of-fearless-to-a-fault)

Comment: To look up the meaning of a word or a phrase, please consult a dictionary. Google is not a dictionary.

Comment: Although, if you Google for **define "to a fault"** you get a reasonable result.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm not a native speaker of English. I looked for "pleasant to a fault" instead. That's the fault.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something good to a fault :

nice to a fault 
pleasant to a fault

is used when the habit of a person of being nice/pleasant to others leads to people think that he/she is being too good for some purpose.

This might affect the person who is being nice in a bad way.

Answer (score -1):

It means someone is regularly so pleasant to people, that the habit is, in fact, a fault.